# How to prove that the twist map is not homotopic to the identity map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose $X$ is an non-empty set. Suppose we have the identity map $f:X \times \{0,1\} \rightarrow X \times \{0,1\}$, $(x,i) \mapsto (x,i)$ for $i \in \{0,1\}$, and we have the twist map $g:X \times \{0,1\} \rightarrow X \times \{0,1\}$, $(x,i) \mapsto (x,j)$ for $i,j \in \{0,1\}$ and $i\ne j$. I think that they are not homotopic, but how do I show it?

Comment: Homotopies have to preserve path-connected components at all times.

Comment: I did not thought of that. Take that $X$ has at least two elements then. Thanks.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro, do you mind elaborating more? I'm quite new to the topic.

Comment: Your notation doesn't make much sense: you are writing ordered pairs like you have a product, but you've written $X\sqcup X$.  Also, when you say "$X$ is a non-empty set", do you mean it has the discrete topology?  Or just it is some non-empty topological space?

Comment: Yes, I notice that my notation doesn't make sense. How do I write it such that it make sense? You know what I mean, the twist map maps the elements on the left $X$ to the right $X$, while the identity map is just what it means.

Comment: @Jerry You want $(x,0)\mapsto (x,1)$ and $(x,1)\mapsto (x,0)$, where $X\sqcup X =X\times \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thanks @PedroTamaroff, I think I have fixed the notation. Then how do I show that the two functions are (not) homotopic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y=X\times\{0,1\}$. Recall that a homotopy from the identity $f$ to the twist map $g$ is a continuous map $H:[0,1]\times Y\to Y$ satisfying $H(0,\cdot)=f(\cdot)$ and $H(1,\cdot)=g(\cdot)$.

Let $x\in Y$. The map $t\mapsto H(t,x)$ is a continuous path from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$. In particular $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ belong to the same (path) connected component.

But connected components of $Y=X\times\{0,1\}$ are subsets of either $X\times\{0\}$ or $X\times\{1\}$, whereas $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ will not belong to the same of these two sets, hence a contradiction.